# Zonky + Spring Boot + Postgres + Flyway with Username and Password

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, flyway

We're using Zonky for integration tests of our Spring Boot applications backed by Postgres and Flyway. Everything works like a charm.
However due to specific DB configuration we have, the application user does not have DDL privileges. So for DB migration, we have a different DB user (with DDL privileges) which we set via `spring.flyway.user`. Unfortunately setting a username for flyway forces `FlywayAutoConfiguration` to create an inline data source specifically for Flyway. This is a problem since Zonky, after starting the Postgres instance, override the original data source bean with the one that has correct url/user/pass. Thus Flyway tries to connect the non-existing database and fails with `Connection Refused`. (See the [issue](https://github.com/zonkyio/embedded-database-spring-test/issues/58) on the repository)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the created data source for Flyway with dedicated credentials is not a bean, Zonky can't do much about it.
One solution is to create a data source bean for Flyway and annotate it with `@FlywayDataSource`. But that means you have to create the main data source as well and make it `@Primary`.
In our case, we used the data source bean created by Spring Boot, so we didn't go the above solution. Instead we added the following to our integration tests:

```java
public class SpringFlywayCredentialsInitializer
        implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext c) {
        for (PropertySource<?> s : c.getEnvironment().getPropertySources()) {
            if (s.containsProperty("spring.flyway.user") 
                    && s instanceof MapPropertySource) {
                ((MapPropertySource) s).getSource().remove("spring.flyway.user");
            }
        }
    }
}
```